# EV3 with NiMH batteries

Tags: ev3, battery

Could I use 6 NiMH 1.2V batteries and keep pressed the small black circle in the battery compartment in order to adjust the battery gauge and low battery alarm?

Comment: Also see http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/6456/3498

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Yes, pressing the button will affect the indicator and low battery alarm/shutdown.

From the official LEGO firmware:

```
#define   BATT_INDICATOR_HIGH           7500          //!< Battery indicator high [mV]
#define   BATT_INDICATOR_LOW            6200          //!< Battery indicator low [mV]

#define   ACCU_INDICATOR_HIGH           7500          //!< Rechargeable battery indicator high [mV]
#define   ACCU_INDICATOR_LOW            7100          //!< Rechargeable battery indicator low [mV]

...

#define   LOW_VOLTAGE_SHUTDOWN_TIME     10000         //!< Time from shutdown lower limit to shutdown [mS]

#define   BATT_WARNING_HIGH             6.2           //!< Battery voltage warning upper limit [V]
#define   BATT_WARNING_LOW              5.5           //!< Battery voltage warning lower limit [V]
#define   BATT_SHUTDOWN_HIGH            5.5           //!< Battery voltage shutdown upper limit [V]
#define   BATT_SHUTDOWN_LOW             4.5           //!< Battery voltage shutdown lower limit [V]

#define   ACCU_WARNING_HIGH             7.1           //!< Rechargeable battery voltage warning upper limit [V]
#define   ACCU_WARNING_LOW              6.5           //!< Rechargeable battery voltage warning lower limit [V]
#define   ACCU_SHUTDOWN_HIGH            6.5           //!< Rechargeable battery voltage shutdown upper limit [V]
#define   ACCU_SHUTDOWN_LOW             6.0           //!< Rechargeable battery voltage shutdown lower limit [V]
```

The `BATT_*` are used when the button is not pressed and the the `ACCU_*` values are used when the button is pressed.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

The small black circle is used by the [Li-ion battery pack](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/EV3-Rechargeable-DC-Battery-45501) from LEGO. This battery pack actually operates at a higher voltage that Alkaline batteries. On the other hand, NiMH batteries operate at a lower voltage than Alkaline, so pressing the small black circle would have the opposite effect of what you are hoping that it will do.

Comment: But Lego battery pack has 7.4v 2200mAh, is almost the same with 6 nihm batteries

Comment: There is actually a wide variation among NiMH batteries. See http://www.philohome.com/batteries/bat.htm for some LEGO related battery comparisons.